# Tumblr Domain and Redirections

Tags: html, .htaccess, redirect, dns, tumblr

```
I currently have my domain pointed to tumblr
domain.com > tumblr ( CNAME etc)
```

and was curious seeming that my domain is pointed to tumblr if there was anyway to redirect my subdirectory's that are on my web-server to somehow be re-directed and show on my tumblr site even tho my website is pointing to tumblr CNAME

```
domain.com/images
domain.com/feed.xml    
domain.com/cms/images
```

my question is how can i get those directory's to work while my domain is pointing to tumblr. is this possible? pointing a sub-domain to tumblr is what im currently doing and would like to make it possible to use my main domain instead of blog.domain.com

Any help would be great

Answer (score 0):

Not possible.
Because if your domain point to Tumblr it means all URLs will be managed by Tumblr's server.

My recommendation: use subdomain as you do now for point to Tumblr.
Like:

```
blog.domain.com
tumblr.domain.com
personal.domain.com
```